How to access Lua global object from another script?
We have a Wireshark dissector written in Lua.
There is a top-level script general.lua which contains:
-- Create a protocol object
xran_protocol = Proto("xran",  "<snip>")        <-- line 27

<snip>

and we have a second script cplane.lua to handle part of the protocol, which contains:
require "general"

-- Create a protocol object
xran_cplane_proto = Proto("cplane",  "<snip>")

<snip>

debug_level = xran_protocol.prefs.c_plane_debug_level         <-- line 348

<snip>


Without the require statement I see:
Lua Error: \cplane.lua:348: attempt to index global 'xran_protocol' (a nil value)

So I added require but then get:
general.lua:27: bad argument 
#2 to 'Proto' (Proto new: there cannot be two protocols with the same 
description) 

Is require causing the code in general.lua to be executed twice?
What is the correct way for the second script to access xran_protocol?

The error says:

Proto new: there cannot be two protocols with the same description.

So what is a description?
According to the documentation, description is the second parameter to the Proto function.
So <snip> is the description, when you do xran_protocol = Proto("xran",  "<snip>") in one file and then xran_cplane_proto = Proto("cplane",  "<snip>") in another you are using the same description twice.
You simply need to change one of those descriptions to make it unique from the other.

Also if you are running general.lua before you do the require in the other file it will get run twice. So to prevent the error from occurring from running the same file twice, you can make it a proper module returning it's self to the caller and not running it outside of the require statement.
local general = {}

-- Create a protocol object
general.xran_protocol = Proto("xran",  "<snip>")   

<snip>
...
return general

Or less properly, you could have the file add its output to the packages which will then return that output to any call of require 'general'
 package.loaded['general'] = { xran_protocol = xran_protocol }

and change the other file to
local general = require "general"
...
debug_level = general.xran_protocol.prefs.c_plane_debug_level



thanks for your answer. Actually, the descriptions are different - I just replaced them in my question by '' to hide the actual values. So I think your second suggestion is most appropriate for me, and does explain what is going on, i.e. the code is executing twice. But I'm afraid I don't understand your solution. Could you please suggest what the solution would look like as code?

@DavidA, I made a few rapid edits before you posted your comment, but there are 2 code examples in the post right now. the shows what you would need to add at the end of the general.lua file, and the next shows the changes that would be needed for the other file. Edit: I have added an example that shows making the general file into a module.

Thanks for your help and comments. I'm trying your second suggestion (package.loaded) but it's not changing the result yet. Should the package.loaded line be at the end of general.lua?

Perhaps I should explain that my scripts work fine (as is) when in the Wireshark global plugins folder. The problem only occurs when I use the personal plugins folder (in AppData on Windows). The global folder is awkward to use because of permission restrictions.

The problem is discussed here: https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/18589

@DavidA the local environment is a crucial factor in your actual problem, I am not sure you can get around it due to the sand boxing, aside from simply combining the scripts into 1 file which is not a great solution.
